# Unity - how to use multiple mappings for the same type and inject into an object

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, unity-container, ioc-container, unity2.0

I'm using Unity 2.0 and in the following code I'm trying to inject a specific tool in the Worker object.

I would like to use the following code.  But ofcourse there is an error "Resolution of the dependency failed". I believe I should be able to do something like this, but I'm having a difficult time figuring it out.

```
IUnityContainer container = new UnityContainer();
container.RegisterType<IWorker, Worker>("Worker")
    .RegisterType<ITool, ToolA>("ToolA")
    .RegisterType<ITool, ToolB>("ToolB")
    .RegisterType<ITool, ToolC>("ToolC");

IWorker worker = container.Resolve<Worker>("ToolA");
```

I know this doesn't work, but how would I resolve this issue?

BarDev

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are two ways you can achieve this:

You can use `ParameterOverride`'s and a two step resolution process...

```
var tool = container.Resolve<ITool>("ToolB");
var worker = container.Resolve<IWorker>("Worker", 
    new ParameterOverride("tool", tool));
```

...assuming that the constructor argument on `Worker` that receives the `ITool` is called 'tool' (multiple `ParameterOverride` instances can be passed to `Resolve`). Any other dependencies (via constructor or property injection) that the named instance of `IWorker` has should be correctly resolved as well.

Alternatively, why not setup named `WorkerA, WorkerB, WorkerC` instances that require the specified `ITool`...

```
container.RegisterType<ITool, ToolA>("ToolA");
container.RegisterType<ITool, ToolB>("ToolB");
container.RegisterType<ITool, ToolC>("ToolC");
container.RegisterType<IWorker, Worker>("WorkerA", 
    new InjectionConstructor(new ResolvedParameter<ITool>("ToolA")));
container.RegisterType<IWorker, Worker>("WorkerB", 
    new InjectionConstructor(new ResolvedParameter<ITool>("ToolB")));
container.RegisterType<IWorker, Worker>("WorkerC", 
    new InjectionConstructor(new ResolvedParameter<ITool>("ToolC")));
```

The disadvantage I suppose with the latter approach is that if `Worker` takes additional constructor parameters you will need to specify them to the `InjectionConstructor` as well, specified in the same order as the constructor you are expecting Unity to use...

```
container.RegisterType<IWorker, Worker>("WorkerA", 
    new InjectionConstructor(typeof(SomeDependency), new ResolvedParameter<ITool>("ToolA"), typeof(SomeOtherDependency));
```

However, Unity will lookup the non-named instance of `SomeDependency` and `SomeOtherDependency` in the above example, so that saves you a bit of work.

Comment: Sweat, this is great.  This was the piece of the puzzle that I was missing.  Now everything is coming together.

Comment: Out of interest, which approach works best for you? In a project I am working, I find uses for both of these approaches actually.

Comment: The second options helps me alot.  The application I'm working on finds classes from dynamicly loaded assemblies that match an interface.  I create the registration for the tool and then create the registration for the worker and specify the tool for the worker.  Its 1 to 1 mapping.  I also have other construction paramerter that I'm passing in to both objects.   I'm also able to implement Policy Injection for AOP task.  This has help me a lot.