# IOC/DI with 2 classes that implement same interface

Tags: c#, .net, design-patterns, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control

I am getting confused with the scenario of 2 classes implementing the same interface and Dependency Injection.

```
public interface ISomething
{
  void DoSomething();
}

public class SomethingA : ISomething
{
  public void DoSomething()
  {

  }
}

public class SomethingAB : ISomething
{
  public void DoSomething()
  {

  }
}

public class Different
{
  private ISomething ThisSomething;

  public Different(ISomething Something)
  {  
    ThisSomething = Something;
  }
}
```

I have seen online examples say that this is valid but you would only use one class at a time. So if the app is running at SiteA you tell your IOC to use SomethingA but if its at SiteB you tell it to use SomethingAB.

Is it considered bad practice therefore to have one app that has 2 classes that implement 1 interface and for it to try to use both classes? If its not how do you tell the IOC which class to use in the relevant circumstance?

**UPDATE: To explain it better I will use Ninject's example:**

```
public class Samurai 
{
    private IWeapon Weapon;

    public Samurai(IWeapon weapon) 
    {
        this.Weapon = weapon;
    }
}

public class Sword : IWeapon
{
...
}

public class Gun : IWeapon
{
...
}

public class WarriorModule : NinjectModule
{
    public override void Load() 
    {
        this.Bind<IWeapon>().To<Sword>();
        this.Bind<IWeapon>().To<Gun>();  //Just an example
    }
}
```

So now you have 2 classes that use IWeapon. Depending on something or a context in your app you want Samurai to have a Sword sometimes or a Gun at other points.  How do you make this happen? How do you handle that "if" scenario??

Comment: Personally wouldn't consider this a bad practice at all - it is a major point of defining interfaces in the first place! As for how to get your IOC container to support this - depends very much on the IOC, all the ones I've used support it with various conditional configuration options. Add a specific IOC to get an answer to that.

Comment: Its not really a specific IOC that the problem exists, its my understanding. I assume its not best practice to instantiate classes myself and if that was ok I assume I'd need to make my IOC globally visible to get the correct instance back which I'm not sure is best practice either.

Comment: The general "best practice" for an IOC is to only have it in one place. There are exceptions, but that is the rule of thumb. One of the exceptions though is where you need this sort of runtime configuration - say you have an event that creates a class that needs configurable dependencies, within the handler for this event (IMO) you can reference your IOC there. A globally visible IOC is a BIG anti-pattern (service locator).

Comment: And for a specific example, see Darin's answer :)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I don't think that this is a bad practice in the general case. There are situations where you could need different implementations of the same interface inside the same application and based on the context use one or another implementation

As far as how to configure your DI to enable this scenario, well, it will depend on your DI of course :-) Some might not support it, others might not, others might partially support it, etc..

For example with [Ninject](http://www.ninject.org/), you could have the following classes:

```
public interface ISomething
{
}

public class SomethingA : ISomething
{
}

public class SomethingB : ISomething
{
}

public class Foo
{
    public Foo(ISomething something)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(something);
    }
}

public class Bar
{
    public Bar(ISomething something)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(something);
    }
}
```

and then use named bindings when configuring the kernel:

```
// We create the kernel that will be used to provide instances when required
var kernel = new StandardKernel();

// Declare 2 named implementations of the same interface
kernel.Bind<ISomething>().To<SomethingA>().Named("somethingA");
kernel.Bind<ISomething>().To<SomethingB>().Named("somethingB");

// inject SomethingA into Foo's constructor
kernel.Bind<Foo>().ToSelf().WithConstructorArgument(
    "something", ctx => ctx.Kernel.Get<ISomething>("somethingA")
);

// inject SomethingB into Bar's constructor
kernel.Bind<Bar>().ToSelf().WithConstructorArgument(
    "something", ctx => ctx.Kernel.Get<ISomething>("somethingB")
);
```

Now when you request an instance of `Foo` it will inject `SomethingA` into it its constructor and when you request an instance of `Bar` it will inject `SomethingB` into it:

```
var foo = kernel.Get<Foo>();
var bar = kernel.Get<Bar>();
```

Comment: Isn't creating 2 classes that accept ISomething duplicate code unnecessarily? Also all of this is done at the start of the program but this may be just be a learning curve thing but I assume that I will no longer be instantiating classes in my code??

Comment: I don't see why this would be duplicate code. You could have 2 classes that require the same contract (ISomething) and the consumer of those classes decide that he needs to inject different implementations depending on the context.

Comment: Also I won't be requesting an instance of Foo or Bar in my application because I would need to make the kernel globally visible??

Comment: No, you never do that. The kernel should be absolutely transparent. You should never directly use it in your consumer code. For example in ASP.NET MVC you could use a custom DependencyResolver with NInject (Ninject.MVC3 NuGet) which will simply inject the dependencies you indicate directly into controllers. In 99% of the applications you never write code such as `kernel.Get<Something>()`. You never need to access the kernel. You configure it once for the lifetime of the application and leave it do its job.

Comment: See updated question. I still don't see in your example why you'd have 2 classes instead of keeping the original 1 class

Comment: You could keep one class if you want. It will depend on what you are trying to achieve. You could keep the Foo class only and then configure your kernel to provide the proper implementation of the interface in the constructor *depending on the context*. You still haven't explained what this context would be but NInject, as I illustrated in my example, allows you to configure the constructor argument using a lambda expression as second argument, so depending on the situation you choose which implementation you need. I just provided an example with 2 classes each using different implementation.

Comment: But of course that you could have a single class. It will all depend on what you are trying to achieve and your exact scenario which I remind you, you haven't yet explained, so please don't ask for general solutions because such do not exist. There are different design approaches depending on what you are trying to achieve. But I've already answered your question about having different implementations of the same interface and having the capacity of the DI framework to handle them and inject the specific implementation depending on some *context*.

Comment: Thanks. I do not know at this stage what that context may be, just trying to learn but I realise at some point or another there will/must be scenarios where 2 classes implement the same interface  so there must be a way to tell the program to use one class or another based on something...whatever that may be.

Comment: @Darin what if we need one implementation at a time e.g. Shoper class constructor has ICreditCard interface. And 2 classes MasterCard and VisaCard classes implement ICreditCard. Shoper needs one class at a time. How to use IOC in this scenario?

Answer (score -1):

i worked with Unity and spring in this context and i think that interest lies in having a weak coupling between packages, ie classes, the ability to change service or point of entry is a consequence of the ioc.

ioc provides flexibility in the use of service, or from the time the services implement the same interface,

If Utilize Service A Service B and Service is in the service package A and package B is in B.
Package A has no reference on the package b, but the service A has a reference on the package containing the interfaces.
Therefore we conclude that we have a weak coupling between package A and package b.

Answer (score -1):

Having multiple implementations mapped to the same interface isn't really bad practice, but it isn't he most common usage pattern.

You didn't specify a specific DI tool, but if you use Unity, you can do this with named instances. See here: [Unity - how to use multiple mappings for the same type and inject into an object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5440888/unity-how-to-use-multiple-mappings-for-the-same-type-and-inject-into-an-object)

Comment: Having multiple implementations of the interface is actually why interfaces are introduced in the first place. Lets not think of interfaces in terms of pupets of dumb DI frameworks.

Comment: The OP asked "Is it considered bad practice" and I replied "
Having multiple implementations mapped to the same interface ISN'T really bad practice" ... we agree, and you downvoted me for it?

Comment: You said that "it isn't the most common usage pattern" when in reality it is more than common. Are you the one writing the interface for the class for the sake of writing an interface and not reusing it anywhere else?